# Sending request as Multipart form data values in asp.net core web api

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

i am currently testing my application and one of my api endpoints use the [FormForm] attribute to get its request.
i ran into a snag while trying to test the endpoint.
Here is what i wrote.

```
[Fact]
        public async Task Create_Bid_Price_Higher_Than_Job_Price_Should_Return_BadRequest()
        {
            // Arrange
            await CreateUserAndAuthorizeAsync();
            
            var jobId = Guid.NewGuid();
           
            // client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

            var formData = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new KeyValuePair<string?, string?>[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string?, string?>("id", jobId.ToString()),
                new KeyValuePair<string?, string?>("title", "job title"),
                new KeyValuePair<string?, string?>("description", "job Description"),
                new KeyValuePair<string?, string?>("initialPrice", "40.33")
            }); 
            
            await  client.PostAsync("api/v1/jobs", formData);
            
            // Act
            var bid = new CreateBidCommand
            {
                Description = "test bid",
                Price = 50.00m
            };

            var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync($"api/v1/bids/{jobId}", bid);
            
            // Assert
            response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
```

from the code above i should recieve a badrequest status code but i am recieving not found because my the job was not created and i suspect i am sending the request formdata in a wrong manner. I have searched all day and cant comeup with a way of sending formdata with different types like string for "title" and decimal for "initialPrice". Please could someone point me in the right direction on how to send formData to a route with a http client. thanks

The endpoint handler:

```
   public async Task<Unit> Handle(CreateBidCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var user = await _context.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == _userAccess.GetCurrentUserId(),
                cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

            if (user == null)
                throw new RestException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, new {error = "You are unauthorized"});
            
            var job = await _context.Jobs.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == request.JobId, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
            
            if (job == null)
            { 
                throw new RestException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, new {error = "Job not found"});
            }

            if (job.User == user)
                throw new RestException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new {bid = "You cannot bid on your own post"});
            
            // delete any previous bid the user has on the job
            var prevBid = await _context.Bids.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.User == user && x.Job == job, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

            if (prevBid != null)
            {
                _context.Bids.Remove(prevBid);
            }

            if (request.Price >= job.InitialPrice)
            {
                throw new RestException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                    new {price = "The price of a bid must be lower than the job price"});
            }
            
            var bid = new Domain.Bid
            {
                Status = BidStatus.Submitted,
                CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
                JobId = request.JobId,
                Description = request.Description,
                Price = request.Price,
                UserId = user.Id,
                User = user,
                Id = request.Id
            };

            await _context.Bids.AddAsync(bid, cancellationToken);

            var created = await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken) > 0;
            if (!created)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error occurred while creating bid");
            }

            return Unit.Value;
        }
    }
```

The api endpoint im testing:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Unit>> CreateJob([FromForm] CreateJobCommand command, CancellationToken ct)
        {
            return await _mediator.Send(command, ct);
        }
```

Comment: Can you show us the api endpoint?

Comment: i have done so. Thanks

Comment: I recreated your `JobsController` and your form data request is OK, i.e, setting a breakpoint and inspecting the values in the controller action method shows the correct values passed from the unit test. So your issue is not with passing form data request. My suspect is that in your `CreateBidCommand`, the value of `jobId` could be incorrect. It seems your request sets the `jobId` on the Url, not on the request body. Unless you explicitly tell your app to use the route value, the default binding will set the default value which might be why you are getting the job not found error.

Comment: Thanks for your input @gerryc.inc , I did set it so that my app uses the route values hence why i put it in the request url. The test passed before when i used json values but the problem arose when i switched the content type to formdata as the user calling the enpoint might also want to send some image files with the request. Thats why i think its the formData part thats causing the problem

Comment: @DBankx, set a breakpoint at `CreateJob` method, check if `CreateJobCommand command` received correct value.